# Clicking/cracking noise while seated

Tags: seatpost, noise

My initial suspicion was that the clicking/cracking noise my bike makes was coming from my bottom bracket. But today, I noticed that when applying full power while standing up, no clicks are present.

When I am not standing, my center of mass obviously goes to the back of the bike. Therefore, I suspect the problem comes either from the back part of the frame (closer to what I hear) or the rear wheel (less probable in my opinion).

My frame/rear wheel have a warranty of 2 years, so I would really like to know if the noise comes from the frame or the wheel. Is there a way to diagnose such a thing? Removing the bottom bracket and inspecting the interior of the frame would be worth?

The only way to rule out a wheel issue would be to get another wheel to test?

Comment: When you stand up, you take the weight away from saddle. So, the first thing to try is to check seat post and saddle and reinstall them.

Comment: I too would check the saddle/seatpost first, they can become loose, or it could be that the rails of the saddle are pulling out of the frame. You could also try lifting the bike and spinning the wheels or looking for a loose spoke

Comment: Yeah, there are a half-dozen different ways the seat or seatpost can make noise.  And generally if there's trouble with the bottom bracket you can either feel it "crunch" as you turn it by hand or you can feel looseness in it if you grab one crank arm and shake it.  (Check especially for one crank arm loose on the shaft.)

Comment: The crunch @DanielRHicks mentions can be quite subtle though. I know one of mine needs replacing but with the chain off you have to be really paying attention to feel it - most of the time, sometimes it's obvious.

Comment: Why do people always assume that noises come from the BB?

Comment: I agree with the others. Check the saddle first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noise was coming from the seat post. Removing the dirt, reapplying some grease and re-tightening the clamp solved the problem. I have also identified that the seat clamp is kind of broken, and the saddle was not leveled.

Thanks for the comments, I didn't know that noises coming from the seat post were that common.

Answer (score 1):

**Align the collar hole with the frame hole**

Another thing I was told at the bike shop, is that both holes should be aligned, seemed to help. They also cleaned up the frame tube with rag and some PTFE based oil. Tightening the clamp as mentioned by OP also seem like a good idea.

Good: holes aligned:

[image]

Bad: holes misaligned:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I point out a thorough review on the bike.

Dismount the Botton Bracket, hubs, derailleurand(front and rear) and chain.

Lubricate parts, then, do a new test.